# Pytorch torchvision MNIST download

Tags: python, pytorch, mnist, torchvision

I'm new to Pytorch and torchvision. I followed a tutorial that is roughly a year old where he tried to download mnist via python and torchvision.

This is how:

```
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

kwargs = {'num_workers': 1, 'pin_memory': True}
train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.MNIST('data', train=True, download=True,
                   transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                   transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])),
    batch_size=64, shuffle=True, **kwargs)
test = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.MNIST('data', train=False,
                   transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                   transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])),
    batch_size=64, shuffle=True, **kwargs)
```

Now my problem is that I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> Downloading http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz to data\MNIST\raw\train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
>
> File "C:/Users/Nico/PycharmProjects/PyTorch/mnist.py", line 13, in 
>       transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])),
>
> File "C:\Users\Nico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\mnist.py", line 68, in **init**
>       self.download()
>
> File "C:\Users\Nico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\mnist.py", line 143, in download
>       download_url(url, root=self.raw_folder, filename=filename, md5=None)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\utils.py", line 73, in download_url
>       reporthook=gen_bar_updater(tqdm())
>
> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'total'

Do any of you guys know what I have to change, or how I can download/use them? As I said earlier I'm new to it and I don't have any clue.

I hope you guys can help me, thanks in advance.

Greetings Nico aka. Myridor

Comment: Works fine on PyTorch 1.0.0.

Comment: I got PyTorch 1.0.1, gonna try it with 1.0.0

Comment: Which version of torchvision you got? I got 0.2.2.post2

Comment: torchvision is '0.2.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem wasn't the code or the naming or anything.

It was the torchvision version. I had 0.2.2.post2 and it worked with 0.2.1!

Comment: I think it should've worked on 0.2.2 as well. You may raise an [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues).